# Can't specify target table for update, delete query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, mysql-error-1093

I want to do what seems like a simple delete in mysql but am having some trouble.  I want to do this:

```
delete from table where col_name not in (select distinct col_name from table);
```

This table does not have a unique key.  When I try this, I get the error:

> You can't specify target table for update in from clause; ErrorNr. 1093

mysql community 5.1

Is there a way i can save the output from this query ->

```
select distinct col_name from table;
```

into temp. table and use it in the delete query?

Comment: Do you want to delete duplicates. Right? Then you should add unique key.

Comment: your query does not make any sense, every column value will be in the returned list of distinct 'col_name'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use an alias.

```
delete from table where col_name not in (select a.col_name from (select distinct col_name from table) a);
```

It should work.

Edit : sorry, I misunderstood the question, and only focus on the SQL Error. The probleme to delete duplicate line with no unique key isn't answered by the above request.

Comment: I used this exact syntax and there is no error, but also nothing gets deleted, ie the table is unchanged and still contains entries.  I verify that
 duplicate entries exist using:`select col_name from table group by col_name having count(*)>1;`

Comment: check that select a.col_name from (select distinct col_name from table) a return the line that you want . edit : in your case, check that select a.col_name from (select col_name from table group by col_name having count(*)>1) a   return something. If not, check the inner query.

Comment: thanks, i checked that `select a.col_name from (select col_name from table group by col_name having count(*)>1) a`, and it did return the rows I wanted to delete, so instead of the syntax above I used this -> `delete from table where col_name in (select a.col_name from (select col_name from table group by col_name having count(*)>1) a)` and that worked!  I am still not sure why the first thing you suggested did not work...

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind it did not work because first you select all the distinct col_name then you say "where col_name not in ( ... )", obviously every col_name will be in the returned distinct list so nothing gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

the answer by @Molochdaa which is accepted is wrong

Explanation.
suppose this is the table

```
col_name |  value
------------------
east     |  10
west     |  15
east     |  10
west     |  15
north    |  5
east     |  10
north    |  5
```

select distinct col_name from table_name gives:

```
col_name
------------------
east     
west     
north
```

now when you write `delete from table where col_name not in ( ... )`then no row will be returned as every column is in the returned list

The correct answer would be (suggested by @jeffery_the_wind)

```
delete from table where col_name in (
   select a.col_name from (
      select col_name from table group by col_name having count(*)>1
   ) a
)
```

Another answer which is more simple

```
delete from table_name
       where rowid not in ( select min(rowid) 
                            from Table_name
                            group by column1..,column2,...column3..)
```